# Python NLTK scores from 0 to 10

Tags: nltk, sentiment-analysis, textblob, vader

I have .txt files IMDB text based movie review. I want to compare this review with star based review from IMDB.
I want to calculate the review's NLTK score to something like 0 to 10 scores (example: 7.5/10) through python NLTK (either textblob or vader). 
how can I calculate the score from NLTK to 0 to 10 score?

Comment: What is a review score? Review of what? What is the score supposed to do?

Comment: If you get a score from 0-1, how do you make it 0-10? =)

Comment: so, I have IMDB text based review, and I want to compare if it is same with star based review from IMDb through sentimental analysis of the text based review

Comment: What is IMDB text based review? And what's the range of values the score/stars can take? How do you change it such that the range is between 0-10?